# how to extract amazon product links using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I'm a Beginner in Python, I just want to scrap product links from amazon page.
for example, I want to scrap this page
http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_in_-2_p_4_18?me=A3MZ96G5C78IVQ&fst=as%3Aoff&rh=p_4%3AFunKo&ie=UTF8&qid=1477811368 and I use this code in python

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = "http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_in_-2_p_4_18?me=A3MZ96G5C78IVQ&fst=as%3Aoff&rh=p_4%3AFunKo&ie=UTF8&qid=1477811368"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

file = open("parseddata.txt", "wb")

links = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'a-link-normal s-access-detail-page a-text-normal'})

for link in links:
print(link.get('href'))
file.write(href + '\n')
file.close()
```

I Just want the products title link as the output. Can anyone tell me where I am doing wrong.

Comment: What do you expect your code to do and what does it actually do? Do you get any error messages or warnings? Are the results wrong and if so, in what regard?

Comment: @Gurpeet Singh you shouldn't be doing this (if it's for something serious), hope you know amazon has an api for developers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `user-agent` to the request `header` to pretend that you are not a robot.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = "http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_in_-2_p_4_18?me=A3MZ96G5C78IVQ&fst=as%3Aoff&rh=p_4%3AFunKo&ie=UTF8&qid=1477811368"

# add header
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36'
}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

file = open(r"parseddata.txt", "w")

links = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'a-link-normal s-access-detail-page a-text-normal'})

for link in links:
    print(link.get('href'))
    file.write(link.get('href')+ '\n')
file.close()
```

## Result

> ```
> https://www.amazon.com/Funko-POP-Marvel-Dancing-Bobble/dp/B00N1EJXUU/ref=sr_1_1/160-5408618-6684940?m=A3MZ96G5C78IVQ&s=merchant-items&ie=UTF8&qid=1477822032&sr=1-1&refinements=p_4%3AFunKo
> https://www.amazon.com/Funko-POP-Movies-Potter-Action/dp/B019JIA4IQ/ref=sr_1_2/160-5408618-6684940?m=A3MZ96G5C78IVQ&s=merchant-items&ie=UTF8&qid=1477822032&sr=1-2&refinements=p_4%3AFunKo
> https://www.amazon.com/FunKo-2390-Funko-Darth-Maul/dp/B005F1QBMK/ref=sr_1_3/160-5408618-6684940?m=A3MZ96G5C78IVQ&s=merchant-items&ie=UTF8&qid=1477822032&sr=1-3&refinements=p_4%3AFunKo
> ........
> ```